# Windows Batch concatenate files contents from subfolder

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I need to put the contents of a file into a single value and also the name of the file from where it came from. I could do it one by one but im having trouble on doing it when looping thru the files in a subfolder. Heres my sample.

I have a files in a subfolder and I need to loop thru all the files and get each of their content. Here are my sample files

```
D:\Projects\Fruits.txt
D:\Projects\Vegetables.txt
```

Fruits.txt has a text content inside

```
Apple
is
good
```

I have a code to get the contents per file. Here it is

```
@echo off    

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set "var="
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (.\Projects\Fruits.txt) do set "var=!var!%%a "
echo("%var%"
```

This will return

```
Apple is good
```

Now I need to do this for all the files as store their contents and the filename on each loop. Something like this

```
For loop code here (
   set FileName = ??
   set FileContent = ??
   echo %FileName% content is %FileContent%
)
```

so in my example every loop should echo something like this

```
Fruits content is Apple is good
Vegetable content is Eat vegetables
```

im having troubles on the looping. if you could point me in the right direction I will appreciate it Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the nesting of one loop inside another like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For %%A In (*.txt) Do (Set "var="
    For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%B In ("%%A") Do Set "var=!var! %%B"
    Echo %%A content is !var:~1!)
Pause
```

*I saw no need to create variables for `FileName` and `FileContent`*

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for /f %%A in ('dir /b *.txt') do (
    set "fileContent="
    for /f "delims=" %%B in ('type "%%~A"') do (
        set "fileContent=!fileContent! %%~B"
    )
    set "fileContent=!fileContent:~1!"

    echo %%~A content is !fileContent!
)
pause
```

- Loops through files
- Get filename and content
- Output them

Comment: Whilst your script will work with the content of the two example files it will not provide the correct output if there are multiple words on one line.

Comment: @Compo Bug should be fixed.